# how can I echo a variable within a string in php?

Tags: php, html

I am trying to use the contents of `$row['file_name']` at the end of the checkbox input field and also use it for the `value=""`.

```
    <?php 

        echo "<form action=\"process.php\" method=\"post\">";

          while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))

          {
          echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"opt[]\"  value=\" \" /> " . $row['file_name'];

          echo "<br />";
          }

        echo "<br><br>";

        echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"formSubmit\" value=\"Send\" />";

        echo "</form>"; 

    ?>
```

Comment: sheesh no0b questions are not welcome

Comment: This isn't about newbie question not being welcome. It's just that you should RTFM :)

Comment: @Grundizer The downvotes are not for a noob question, it's because your question is not well structured. You have to read deep into the code to know what you're asking. You're not showing what you've tried, and what went wrong when you tried it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do

```
 echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"opt[]\"  value=\"{$row['file_name']}\" /> " . $row['file_name'];
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$variable = "world";
echo "Hello, $variable";

//or
echo "Hello, {$variable}"

//or
echo 'Hello, '.$variable.'!';  // .(dot) concatenates strings
```

using double quotes(") you can use variable directly in in string (ex 1), using single quotes(') variable content doesn't:

```
  echo 'Hello, $variable'; //OUTPUT: Hello, $variable
  echo 'Hello, '.$variable; //OUTPU: Hello, world
```

Comment: Wow... Always like reading answers to questions. Never could figure out why sometimes a variable inside quotes would render correctly and sometimes not. Never correlated single and double quotes as the issue. Thanks for this piece.

Answer (score 3):

You can echo the variable within your string like so

```
echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"opt[]\"  value=\"$row[file_name]\" /> $row[file_name]";
```

In order to do this (embed any php variable in a string), the quotes defining your string must be double quotes (as you have it).

Also note, you must remove the quotes that define the string index in your array when embedding the array element in a string, or surround the array element in curly braces like so:

```
echo "{$row['file_name']}";
```

Comment: I highly recommend putting the {} around a variable interpolation when there's an index on it.

Comment: I've seen that before, but never understood the purpose for it. Would you mind explaining?

Comment: This emits an E_NOTICE because of `undefined constant file_name, assumed 'file_name'`.  I'd follow webjprgm's advice and use {} so you can use the single quotes around the index.

Comment: @drew010 I do not get an `E_NOTICE`. Also, if I have an existing constant named `file_name`, it does *not* pick up that constant, but assumes correctly it is an string index.

Comment: @drew010 I believe you are referring to doing it like this *outside* of a string.

Answer (score 2):

Your code can look cleaner if you let html print itself and use PHP for templating

```
<form action="process.php" method="post">

  <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)): ?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="opt[]"  value="<?php echo $row['file_name'] ?>" />
    <br />
  <?php endwhile; ?>

  <br /><br />
  <input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

Comment: This is how it should be done, then the OP's original question is irrelevant